# CSS alignment Issue with Headers

Tags: css

Im a newbie to CSS and created this html file for my testing...but the results are not what I expected..

Here are my questions,

1. What would be the correct width of my IE window.
2. What would be the perfect height of my window..When I specify a value nothing changes.
3. I have created 3 divisions- Header, Footer and content..When I view it..there is a big space between each of these sections..Why do they occur?

Code follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body
            {
                background-color:#d0e4fe;
                width:1400px;
                height:1000px;
            }

            h1
            {
                color:orange;
                text-align:center;
            }

            #div-1
            {
                background-color:red;
            }
            #div-2
            {
                background-color:Green;
            }
            #div-3
            {
                background-color:Blue;
            }


        </style>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="div-1">
            <h1>Header<h1>
        </div>

        <div id="div-2">
            <h1>Content<h1>
        </div>

        <div id="div-3">
            <h1>Footer<h1>
        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What were the results you expected?  Maybe you should provide a Fiddle link.

Comment: The spaces that you're seeing are generated by the `h1` elements, and they're an example of what is called the "Box Model".  Treat each block element in HTML as though it were a box, it has a cushy area on the outside, which is defined by the "padding" parameter, the thickness of the edge of the element, which is defined as the "border", and then the area from the edge to the content inside, which is defined as the "margin".  Get to know and understand these parameters, and your CSS learning will make much more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't define the width or height of the window in CSS. It just doesn't happen. You may specify the width of particular elements on your page, but that is a slightly different matter. Remove your `height` and `width` properties.

Second, your divisions have spaces between them due to the default margins that are set on `h1` tags. If you want to remove them, then set `margin: 0` on your `h1` in your CSS.

Third, you may want to check out [this CSS tutorial at HTMLDog](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssbeginner/)

Answer (score 2):

1. The width on your body tag should be set to "width: 100%;"  This will cause the body tag to take up the entire width of the window, and your colored div sections will also stretch the full width.
2. You can set the height on the body tag to either "height: 100%;" or "height: auto;".  Depends on what you are doing exactly.
3. The space is coming from your h1 tags you have inside each of those divs.  They have a browser-defaulted margin set to them.  If you set the css property to "margin: 0px" that should eliminate all that extra space.

Comment: Width, by default, is already 100%. Don't bother setting it. And setting heights in CSS is generally a bad idea (yes, there are exceptions, but this is not one of them).

Comment: Thanks for adding that.  I got a little confused it looks like due to him having a width set.  That's what I get for not thinking through and just answering :)